# How to programatically find which view is being scrolled to the top in the screen?

Tags: java, android, scrollview, android-nestedscrollview

I have four recyclerviews inside a NestedScrollview and i am setting tag for each recyclerview elements in order to design sticky header.

I have to get the view at the top most position so that i can get the tag of that view and implement sticky.

After i am searching through forums, still i didn't able to get the correct code on getting the view at the top position of a screen.

Any help on this will be really helpful for my project

Answer (score 0):

Set and implement `OnScrollListener` on your `Activity` class. Then you should `override` `onScroll`, `onScrollStateChanged` which will provide you the view is scrolled and its state. Look at it - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.OnScrollListener.html

Comment: It returns (NestedScrollView v) in the implemented method and also like recyclerview i doesn't gives the top visible position as first view. Instead what the nestedscrollview layout contains as the first child will be returned as the top view.

Comment: You should get top visible from OnScroll method. Follow it - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25833164/get-visible-position-of-listview-item